# Why class fields needs to be compile time constants (That is they should be assigned the value in one line)?

Tags: java, instance-variables

```
      public class A{

      int aa;

      aa = 10;  //compile error



       }
```

is the compile error because class fields need to be compile time constant? is this design to improve performance?

Comment: They don't need to be compile-time constants.  It's because you can't have statements inside a class.

Comment: Then why is this allowed: int aa = 10;

Comment: Serg and Elliot, I know how it is done, but my question is why it is not allowed to have this statement inside a class? What is the reason?

Comment: @CM1 Because you can't have raw statements without a method, constructor or initialization block to contain them. What order would the JVM evaluate statements if you could enter them in any order? Remember, unlike Scala, Java isn't a scripting language.

Answer (score 0):

Assignment needs to be within some method or constructor. 
Kind of

```
public class A{
      int aa;
      public A() {
         aa = 10;  
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to have `aa = 10;` in a *method*, in a *constructor* **or** in an *initialization block*.

In a *setter* (or *mutator*) method like

```
int aa;
void setA(int aa) {
    this.aa = aa;
}
```

**or** in a *constructor* like

```
public A(int aa) {
    this.aa = aa;
}
```

**or** an *initialization block* like

```
{
    this.aa = aa;
}
```